# Solving a second order ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve below equation for $y(r)$ in 3D:

$$a\nabla^2 y(r) = b y(r) \Sigma_i \delta(r-r_{0i}).$$

In the case where there is no $y$ in rhs, it could be solved easily. But what about this case? Could anyone solve it?

Comment: b and a are constants.If the question is not clear, please let me do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful approach is by using the Fourier transform. One has
$$
   -k^2a{\tilde y}(k)=b\int d^3x e^{i{\bf k}\cdot{\bf x}}y(r)\delta(r-r_0).
$$
Then,
$$
   -k^2a{\tilde y}(k)=2\pi b\int_{-1}^1d\cos\theta\int dr e^{ikr\cos\theta}\int_0^\infty dry(r)\delta(r-r_0).
$$
This gives
$$
   -k^2a{\tilde y}(k)=2\pi b\int_{-1}^1d\cos\theta\int_0^\infty dr e^{ikr\cos\theta}y(r)\delta(r-r_0).
$$
So,
$$
 -k^2a{\tilde y}(k)=\frac{4\pi b}{kr_0}y(r_0)\sin(k r_0).
$$
The Fourier transform is given by
$$
   {\cal F}\left(\frac{\sin(kr_0)}{k^3}\right)=\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}e^{-i{\bf k}\cdot{\bf x}}\frac{\sin(kr_0)}{k^3}=
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi^2 r}\int_0^\infty dk\frac{\sin(kr_0)\sin(kr)}{k^2}=\frac{1}{8\pi r}[|r+r_0|-|r-r_0|.]
$$

Let us consider instead the equation
$$
     a\Delta_2 y=by(r)\sum_i\delta(r-r_{0i}).
$$
Again, we can perform a Fourier transform being the equation linear and one gets
$$
    -k^2a{\tilde y}(k)=\frac{4\pi b}{k}\sum_i\frac{y(r_{0i})\sin(kr_{0i})}{r_{0i}}.
$$
Then, all runs as above as we have to compute the inverse of the Fourier transform of $\sin(kr_{0i})/k^3$ and the final result is
$$
   y(r)=\frac{b}{2ar}\sum_i\frac{y(r_{0i})}{r_{0i}}[|r+r_{0i}|-|r-r_{0i}|]
$$

Comment: In the question, if there was \sigma_i \delta(r-r_i) instead of \delta(r-r_0), how does th answer changes?

Comment: Your question is rather interesting and I will use the linearity of the equation to get the solution. You should get $\sum_i y(r_i)\delta(r-r_i)$ and so, your solution is just a sum of solutions as given in the answer.

Comment: No the question is not what you think. I have just edited the question

Comment: But what should be the meaning of this $r_i$ with respect to $r_0$? In this way it seems that you just changed the name to a constant.

Comment: r_0i is a constant which it's value depends on i

Comment: @OliverRange I have already given you the answer in the comment. The equation is linear and so having $\Delta_2 y=y(r)\sum_i\delta(r-r_{0i})$ just amount to say that the solution is $y=\sum_i y_i$ with each $y_i$ the one I obtained in my answer.

Comment: Does i index in y_i go next to zero?

Comment: I add the explanation to the answer.

Comment: Please also use a and b in your answer

Comment: Done. I hope this help.

Comment: I think the answer is not correct. because there are some sinks in r_0 and y(r_0) divereges

Comment: The answer is correct because you set no conditions at all on $y(r_0)$ and $r_0$ themselves. You not even stated the problem properly. As you have noticed, all this costs some effort by my side and a better behavior by you would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to bother you

Comment: I am just trying to help you. Nothing else and this is what we try to do here in this group. Of course, to be able to do that relies mostly on the way interactions go on and the questions are stated.

Comment: You are right and I am really happy for your help :). I'm just not sure if it is correct completely. Just this

Comment: Yes, I understand your concerns but the case with $r_0=0$ should be treated differently, assuming $y(0)$ is meaningful. In this case the solution is rather standard being this a Poisson equation. To consider it, just sum this solution to the full solution I gave. But if $y(0)=0$ than this case is not relevant.

Comment: d^3k is equal to k^2 dk. but you didn't considered it

Comment: Sorry but I did it. Otherwise I would not have got the right result. The $k$ that you did not see was eaten up by angular integration.

Comment: What about dr^3?

Comment: What about dr^3?

Comment: The computation is there for you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

let $b/a=c$ and $\xi=r-r_{0}$, the equation is
$$\nabla^{2}y(\xi)=cy(\xi)\delta(\xi)$$
For $\xi\neq{0}$ one has
$$\nabla^{2}y(\xi)=0$$

Which is the Laplace's equation and is easy to solve. The boundary conditions at $\xi=0$ are obtained by integrating the equation over the volume $\Omega$ centered at $\xi=0$ such that $vol(\Omega)\rightarrow0$
$$\lim_{vol(\Omega)\rightarrow0}\int_{\Omega}\nabla^{2}y(\xi)dV=cy(0)$$
Using the Gauss theorem this may also be written as
$$\lim_{vol(\Omega)\rightarrow0}\int_{\partial\Omega}\nabla{y}(\xi)\cdot{n}dS=cy(0)$$
Say you solved the equation in polar coordinates $(r, \phi, \theta)$, this may be written as
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow0}4\pi{r}^{2}\frac{dy(r, \theta, \phi)}{dr}=cy(0, \theta, \phi)$$

Comment: What is the answer for y(r) finally?